Insert unique_ptr in a map and keep ownership of unique_ptr on failed insertion with inheritance
Yesterday I asked this question that got answered properly Insert unique_ptr in a map and keep ownership of unique_ptr on failed insertion.
I recite it here because the problem is now a little bit extended:
I have a method addToMap that accepts a string as a key and an unique_ptr as rvalue -reference that should then be emplaced in a map. If the insertion fails the caller of the method should keep the ownership. For the method try_emplace(...) in the map class this is possible.
This works now, if the unique_ptr holds an integer or non inherited class. If I use an abstract class as template parameter the suggested solution does not work anymore.
Here the sample code: https://godbolt.org/z/MeeYGEE9n
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    void addToMap(const std::string& key, std::unique_ptr<T>&& value)
    {
        _map.try_emplace(key, std::move(value));
        std::cout << "Inside " << value << std::endl;
        // after a failed insertion value is not empty and usable
    }

    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<T>> _map;
};

class IBar
{
public:
    virtual ~IBar() = default;

    virtual void Zoo() = 0;
};

class BarImp : public IBar
{
public:
    ~BarImp() override = default;
    void Zoo() override { }
};

int main()
{
    {
        auto a = std::make_unique<int>(0);
        auto b = std::make_unique<int>(1);

        Foo<int> foo;
        foo.addToMap("0", std::move(a)); 
        foo.addToMap("0", std::move(b)); 

        std::cout << "Outside " << a << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Outside " << b << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    {
        auto a = std::make_unique<BarImp>();
        auto b = std::make_unique<BarImp>();

        Foo<IBar> foo;
        foo.addToMap("0", std::move(a)); 
        foo.addToMap("0", std::move(b)); 

        std::cout << "Outside " << a << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Outside " << b << std::endl;
    }
}

Example output:
Inside 00000000
Inside 010F3F88
Outside 00000000
Outside 010F3F88

Inside 00000000
Inside 010F26D0
Outside 00000000
Outside 00000000

As it can be seen, the last 2 "Outside" are empty but the last one should not be empty. Why is that and how can I achieve to correct it? As you can see the map emplace is working correctly (line 5 & 6 of output).

There's an implicit conversion from std::unique_ptr<BarImp> to std::unique_ptr<IBar> which creates a temporary, the temporary takes ownership of the pointer

ok so without using auto it works... Can I enforce by method signature that no temporary is created?

You could change your rvalue reference to an lvalue reference I suppose, that won't bind to temporaries or allow implicit conversions (other than in visual studio which is broken in this regard)

Consider making addToMap a template, i.e. template<typename U>void addToMap(const std::string& key, std::unique_ptr<U>&& value). That will prevent conversions.

@alagner thanks your solution works even for MSVC. I also do not need to specify the template type when calling addToMap!

As pointed out by Alan in the comment section, there is an implicit conversion from std::unique_ptr<BarImp> to std::unique_ptr<IBar>, creating a temporary. The behaviour of std::move with regard to the value after the move is unspecified. cppreference.com states:

Unless otherwise specified, all standard library objects that have been moved from are placed in a "valid but unspecified state", [...]

Hence you cannot rely on a particular behaviour once you have moved your std::unique_ptr<BarImp> into a std::unique_ptr<IBar>.
A simple solution to this problem is to make the addToMap function a template, accepting unique_ptr of a different type, so the implicit type conversion only happens inside the try_emplace():
    template<typename U>
    void addToMap(const std::string& key, std::unique_ptr<U>&& value)
    {
        _map.try_emplace(key, std::move(value));
        std::cout << "Inside " << value << std::endl;
        // after a failed insertion value is not empty and usable
    }

With gcc 13, the output changes then to:
Inside 0
Inside 0x5ffa465e92d0
Outside 0
Outside 0x5ffa465e92d0

Inside 0
Inside 0x5ffa465e92b0
Outside 0
Outside 0x5ffa465e92b0


The unspecified state of moved from objects is a general thing (see Unless otherwise specified), for unique_ptr it's very tightly specified, it'll be null: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr
